# Pushing additional key values without overwriting existing key values in an array

Tags: templating, craft3, array

For an existing key in an associative array, I'm trying to push a new value to it without overwriting the existing values in the key. I've tried this:

```
{% set myArray = {
    myKey: [
        'value1',
    ]
} %}
{% set myArray = myArray|merge({key: 'value2'}) %}
```

But this returns `[ 'myKey' : 'value2']`. I'm trying to get it to return `[ 'myKey' : [ 0 => 'value1', 1 => 'value2']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
{% set myArray = {
    myKey: [
        'value1',
    ]
} %}

{% set myArray = myArray|merge({myKey: myArray.myKey | merge(['value2']) }) %}
```